# Keras : How to find indices from a tensor for a particular value similar to numpy.where()

Tags: keras

I am searching for a Keras command which is similar to python `"numpy.where()"` command. Basically, my idea is to extract the indices from a tensor. In python I can do simply `f_j=(np.where(X==j))` which gives me specific `indices(f_j)` for the value `j`.

ex:

```
X= [0 1 1 0 0 2 3 ]

f_j=(np.where(X==1))

f_j= [1 2]
```

Is there is any similar function which I can use for this purpose ?

I tried to write array search inside a tensor. However, I end up with error when calling `"if K.equal():"` line as

> TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed. Use if t
>   is not None: instead of if t: to test if a tensor is defined, and use
>   TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the
>   value of a tensor.

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred:

b=K.equal(y_true,0)

b=K.cast(b,dtype='float32')

for i in range(0,5):

if K.equal(b[i],1):

........

y_true = [0 1 1 0 0 2 3 ]
```

Comment: what do you want to do if the if condition is met?

Comment: I want to find indices which equal to a number. As example:

y_true = [0 1 1 0 0 2 3 ]
for i in range(0,7)
a=[]
if y_true(i)==1
a.append(i)

then a=[1,2]

I want to do it using keras. However, keras boolean tensors does not support if command

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
from keras import backend as K
value = 5
wh = K.tf.where(K.tf.equal(x,value))
```

when your backend is tensorflow.

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there anything similar that works for other backends?

Comment: this will not work, tf.where return a cordinate not index