# Implementation of choosing the most confident output with Keras functional API

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm working at text classification problem. Now I'm trying to improve results by using multiple outputs from models trained on differenf subsets of dataset i.e. using "bagging". Every model consists of convolutional and recurrent layers combination and has softmax output with three values.

Recently I've tried to use API's Average() function. But it just averages all outputs from best to worst ones. Another variants like Maximum() still doesn't help enough because, as far as I know, maximization of every value spoils "softmax" effect.

```
def MultiInputClassifier(input_length, input_num, class_num, classifiers):
inputs_list = []
outputs_list = []

for i in range(input_num):
    inputs = Input(shape=(input_length,), name='input_{}'.format(i))
    inputs_list.append(inputs)

    model_output = classifiers[i](inputs)
    outputs_list.append(model_output)

preds = Average()(outputs_list)
model = Model(inputs=inputs_list, outputs=preds, name='final_model')
model.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

Probably, the solution would be to choose the most confident output in every specific case. So, is there any way to choose the whole output by finding a maximum value along all axes?

If we have [0.2, 0.7, 0.1] and (0.3, 0.6, 0.1], we will choose just (0.2, 0.7, 0.1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your outputs are

```
output_1 = [0.2, 0.7, 0.1] 
output_2 = [0.3, 0.6, 0.1]
```

you could collect them in an array:

```
outputs = np.array([output_1, output_2])
```

and then select the row with the maximum value

```
outputs[np.where(outputs == np.max(outputs))[0],:]
```

Comment: Thanks... But is there any way to implement it with the Keras functional API? It makes possible to use all Keras metrics like (accuracy/loss). With raw numpy it would be tricky :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553646/keras-how-to-find-indices-from-a-tensor-for-a-particular-value-similar-to-nump

Comment: Well, i'm trying to use `x[K.tf.where(K.tf.equal(x, K.max(x)))[0],:]` where x is outputs but it throws "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" :(

Comment: can you check the shapes of K.tf.equal(x, K.max(x)))[0] and K.tf.equal(x, K.max(x))) ?

Comment: Tensor("most_confident_1_2/strided_slice:0", shape=(?, 5), dtype=bool)
Tensor("most_confident_1_2/Equal_1:0", shape=(2, ?, 5), dtype=bool)

Comment: I've solved the problem with `K.tf.gather(x, K.tf.where(K.tf.equal(x, K.max(x)))[0][0])`